# Joption game logic

Tags: java

I have built on the idea i was given on using Joption, I would appreciate if someone could help me

```
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class TestOptionPane {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
            TestOptionPane.class.getResource("/resources/android.jpg"));
    String answer = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            null, "Spell the Image", "Spell the Image", 
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, icon, null, null);

    if (answer.equals("Android")) {
        System.out.println("Yayyy");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Ummm.. and do _what_ with the images? Short answer, change your `Word` constructor to accept an Image. If that doesn't do it for you, clarify your question, so we actually know what you are talking about.

Comment: i am making a guess the word game and these are the random categories that show up. rather than just having words i would like to show images

Comment: Show them _where_? Are you making a GUI program?

Comment: yes it shows up on the gui.. it comes up with food as the category and and pizza as the guessing word. the whole point of the game is to spell.

Comment: Show your GUI code so we can further help you, and where exactly in the GUI you want the image to be displayed

Comment: I think he just wants to add the path of the images to the `Word` Object

Comment: i have not used swing so how can i?

Comment: So is your program just currently a console program?

Comment: @luis Lavieri how do im implement ur suggestions?

Comment: I edited my post. You are not using `Swing` at this moment. It is an OOP question.

Comment: By the way, you don't need the System.exit in the end in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform that you are working on. For instance, if you are working for `Android`, you would have to change the `Word` constructor and add a `Bitmap` type. For instance,

```
public class Word{

private String name;

private String imagePath;

public Word(String _name, String _imagePath){
    this.name = _name;
    this.imagePath= _imagePath;
}

}
```

Example:

```
Word newWord = new Word("Pizza", "path/image.png");
```

But at the end, you could change the `Bitmap` type for anything you want, and then add it to a `Map` or in your case a `LinkedList`.

**EDIT**: I am reading in your comments that you are doing a `GUI`. You would have to use a `String type`, and add the `path` to the image to the constructor.

Comment: It is `Java`. Do you want to add the `path` of the image to the `Word` object?

Answer (score 0):

Since your program is just a console program, and you have no experience in Swing, I'll give you a simple solution for showing an image in a `JOptionPane`

What you can do is have you `Word` take an `ImageIcon`

```
private ImageIcon icon;
private String name;

Word(String name, String type, ImageIcon icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public ImageIcon getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

You can create the `Word` in your `WordRepository` like

```
ImageIcon appleIcon = new ImageIcon(WordRepository.class.getResource("/resources/apple.png"));
Word apple = new Word("apple", "food", appleIcon);
```

Where your file structure should look like

```
ProjectRoot
         src
             resources
                     apple.png
```

Then when you want to show it in your program, you can just show it in a `JOptionPane` like

```
Word word = wordRepository.getRandomWord();
ImageIcon icon = word.getIcon();

String answer = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                 null, "Spell the Image", "Spell the Image", 
                 JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, icon, null, null);

if (answer.equals(word.getName())) {
    System.out.println("Yayyy");
}
```

---

See the [JOptionPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html) for more details on what the arguments are that I pass to it.

---

You can use this as a simple test program. Just change the path to your image correctly and the String you want the input to equal

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestOptionPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
                TestOptionPane.class.getResource("/resources/android.jpg"));
        String answer = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null, "Spell the Image", "Spell the Image", 
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, icon, null, null);

        if (answer.equals("Android")) {
            System.out.println("Yayyy");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]